# Insert values from -large- array into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

```
        stdClass Object
(
    [ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12345671
            [1] => 12345672
            [2] => 12345673
            [3] => 12345674
            [4] => 12345675
            [5] => 12345676
            [6] => 12345677
                 .
                 .
                 .                 
                 .
        )
```

I have a long array that includes user ids.
I want to insert each array as a new row into mysql. How can ı do this?

I have tried this but it doesn't worked

```
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $content as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.$con->real_escape_string($row['ids']).'")';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (ids) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck in specific? Why didn't you efforts work? Have you read our [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Comment: There are parentheses missing around every single item of your VALUES list: it's `VALUES ('12345671'), ('12345672'), ...` not `VALUES '12345671' , ...` If your id column has got the data type INT then there's no need for single quotes around the values too. It would a good idea to move to mysqli or PDO with parameterized prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a column count mis-match by doing that - and `table` is a reserved word, as your resulting query will look something like

```
INSERT INTO `table` (ids) VALUES 12345676, 12345677
```

This is wrong.

You need your ending query to be like;

```
INSERT INTO `table` (ids) VALUES (12345676), (12345677)
```

To achieve this with PHP, we can do the following;

```
<?php

$a = array("ids" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));

$input_lines = implode(",", $a['ids']);

echo preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "($0)", $input_lines);
```

[Preview](https://eval.in/189673)

That would make the resulting PHP code

```
<?php

$a = array("ids" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
$input_lines = implode(",", $a['ids']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (ids) VALUES ". preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "($0)", $input_lines);
```

[Preview](https://eval.in/189676)